# differ NaN values from real zero

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have found out that `isnull()`, `np.isnan()` cannot distinguish zeros from `NaN`. Are there any good tools?
I need to filter `NaN` values in the dataframe, but not zeros (actually, I want to mask `NaN` in the heatmap with a color different than all numeric values including zeros). 
What can you advise?

Comment: `"I have found out that isnull(), np.isnan() cannot distinct zeros from NaN"` - how did you come to this conclusion??

Answer (score 2):

> I have found out that isnull(), np.isnan() cannot distinct zeros from
>   NaN

Can you check again? Because last time I checked it works.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.isnan(0)
False
>>> np.isnan(np.nan)
True
```